# Convert certain values in the column to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Any idea how to convert table in the left to the right table?

[image: Two tables]

Comment: Did you try anything you can show?

Answer (score 0):

Just be systematic.  Pick out parts in input that you want in output

```
import datetime as dt

# build as per pic of input
df = pd.DataFrame({"rank":["ALLIED HEALTH - MED LAB","SO(M) - PATH"] 
              +[d.strftime("%b-%Y") for d in pd.date_range(dt.date(2019,4,1), dt.date(2020,4,1), freq="1M")]})
df = df.assign(hospital="AHNH",fte=np.nan)

### CREATE OUTPUT ###
df.assign(discipline=df.iloc[0,0], month=df["rank"], rank=df.iloc[0,1]).iloc[2:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt help. Apologize that I only capture part of the input and actually there are several ranks under the same discipline. Is there a systemic way to transform the dataframe like a for loop?

Comment: Provide a sample of your data in your question with multiple ranks as text Generally for loops are an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple ranks under the same discipline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KiiM.png)